# ansible from_json filter - unable to use {{ inventory_hostname }}

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible 2.6 and I have been trying to pass json object as --extra-vars from python API. Although I am able to send json object successfully, but I am not able to use `{{ inventory_hostname }}` in the filters while parsing the dict.

The below playbook configuration works perfectly for this json object:

**Python API part:**

```
    extra_vars = {"example_list":[{"name":"first","foo":"bar","item":"thud"},{"name":"second","foo":"grunt","item":"baz"}]}
    extra_vars_json = json.dumps(extra_vars)
    self.variable_manager.extra_vars = {'json_var' : extra_vars_json} 

executor = PlaybookExecutor(
                        playbooks=[self.playbook], inventory=self.inventory, variable_manager=self.variable_manager, loader=self.loader, options=self.options, passwords={})
```

**Playbook config:**

```
- name: Get the json string
  set_fact:
    xyz: "{{({{ json_var }} | from_json).example_list | map(attribute='foo') | list }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
```

Now, what if example_list is a hostname. How would I use {{ inventory_hostname }} in this case. I tried this:

```
xyz: "{{({{ json_var }} | from_json).{{inventory_hostname}} | map(attribute='foo') | list }}"
```

but it didn't work and throwing exception:

> fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ (json_var | from_json).(inventory_hostname }}"}`**

Answer (score 0):

Tested to work with your example:

```
xyz: "{{ ( json_var | from_json )[inventory_hostname] | map( attribute='foo' ) | list }}"
```

As an aside, [you can pass raw JSON](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) to the Ansible extra-args, so you could simplify your playbook and avoid the need to explicitly decode in the tasks, assuming your calling app could be modified to support.